# Ubuntu 12.04 In tray Icon -> "Edit Connections..." not clickable

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, indicator

I am use ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-panel, I press network tray icon then Open following small menu,

[image]

Last "Edit Connections..." not clickable how can I edit my wired and wifi connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can access this menu by:
`VPN Connections`-->`Configure VPN`-->`Ethernet`-->`Wired Connection`-->`Edit`

Comment: **VPN Connections** also not clickable.

Comment: Did you try to restart your computer?Also in the image i can see that `VPN Connections` are clickable.

Comment: Yeah i restarted my laptop. VPN is clickable. Once I click open other two option that are not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04 downgrade packages ("force version" with Synaptic) from precise-updates to precise for:

- unity-greeter 0.2.9-0ubuntu1.5 -> 0.2.8-0ubuntu1
- libnm-gtk0 0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2.4 -> 0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2
- libnm-gtk-common 0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2.4 -> 0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2
- network-manager-gnome 0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2.4 -> 0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2

and disable auto update in software sources until the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1424119) will not be fixed!
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1427800